# Can I change a login pop up in a wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Im using a wordpress theme called classifieds by templatic. On the login pop up it asks you for the user name and the password.
Can I change that so that it asks for the Email instead of the user?.

Comment: You can. Assuming it's the theme that's providing the login popup, then all you need to do is check its source code and make the adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. First, I would make a child theme from your original theme. Then find the place in the source code where the text you want to change is, and do that in the child theme. This way if your theme is ever updated you won't overwrite your changes.

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/